# How to get Current Month's Starting and End dates in SSRS report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am working on SSRS Report, I have used 2 Date selection calendar,
From Date and To date, So in From Date the Current months starting date should be as default date, and into the to date the Last date of the current month should be by default.
Should I use Expression? or By SQL Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using T-SQL for 2012 version or higher it's quite simple, using [`DateFromParts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) to get the first day of the month and [`EOMonth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) to get the last day:

```
DECLARE @Today Date = GETDATE();
DECLARE @FirstDayOfTheMonth date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@Today), MONTH(@Today), 1),
        @LastDayOfTheMonth date = EOMONTH(@Today);
```

Comment: I used this as per the requirment
select DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) as StartDate,EOMONTH(GETDATE()) as EndDate